# How to make selectRow in Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel

Tags: extjs, grid

Working on project written on ExtJs 3.1.1:

I want to select whole row in a `Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel` by `selectRow()` but this method is absent.

If I change grid type to `Ext.grid.GridPanel` everything becomes fine.

Why the behavior of `Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel` differs from `Ext.grid.GridPanel`?
How to select whole row?

My grid is as follows:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        id : 'g',
        store: store,
        trackMouseOver: true,
            ...
});
```

Event code is like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('g').on('click', function (e) {
    Ext.getCmp('g').getSelectionModel().selectRow(1);

    // this fires error "Uncaught TypeError: 
    //Ext.getCmp(...).getSelectionModel(...).selectRow is not a function"
}) ;
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2n8m&view/

Comment: Can someone help on below- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107141/ext-js-call-between-2-controller-and-store-read-method-and-rest-api

Comment: @Sergey, your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22089378) in february was rejected as it was no improvement (it literally changed nothing), there is no need to [suggest it again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24031695)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the clue!
You need to rewrite RowSelectionModel:

```
grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
  store: myStore,
  height: 500,
  border: false, frame: false,
  cm: myColumnModel,
  selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
```